# I cannot install via netinstall without trusty-updates or trusty-security repositories disabled

Tags: system-installation, preseed

I'm  trying the network installation (preseed) of trusty suite. But apparently the commands:

```
pkgsel  pkgsel/upgrade  select  none
d-i     pkgsel/upgrade  select  none
pkgsel  pkgsel/update-policy    select  none
d-i     pkgsel/update-policy    select  none
```

Do not work. Any help?

Comment: I make a local repository with trusty and trusty-security suites only. Then I make a unattended installation pointing to it. My installation only have packages from this suites, what is great, but may local repository is not what I want yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is it. My solution was the local repository without trusty-updates suite. Regards.